# How to connect my Ubuntu server to VirtualBox Ubuntu guest installation

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, remote-login

I have a server machine running Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS. I have installed exactly the same OS version on a VirtualBox guest running on Windows 8 guest machine.

Both machines have internet connectivity.

By running `ifconfig` on both machines, I obtained the I.P addresses of the server and VBox guests as:

```
192.168.1.9
10.0.2.15
```

Now, I can ping the server machine from the VBox guest, but can't ping the VBox guest from the server machine.

I want to be able to log onto the server machine (as myself - both machines have the same logon name and password), from the VBox machine.

What do I nedd to do in order to be abe to connect onto the server machine from the VBox guest - as myself (i.e. a remote login)?

Comment: What network adapter configuration is on the Guest?  NAT?  Bridged?

Comment: @ThomasW. The network adapter configuration is on the Guest is NAT. I have to point out that it is important that the Guest OS has internet access, since I will be retrieving data from the internet on the guest machine, and saving it on the server (using sshfs).

Comment: To clarify then, it seems I want to be doing things (it's not clearto me whether they are separate). 1. Connect remotely to the server as myself, from the host OS      2. mount one of the drives of the server on the guest OS (so I can save data to it). HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few different options open to you.  A 'default' connection in a VM will be set to "NAT".

---

What **NAT** essentially does is it makes your computer act a little like a router, routing traffic between the VMs and the connection that the computer is on.  Essentially, the VMs 'masquerade' to other things on your network or to the internet as your computer (or the router your computer is behind, if it's behind a router).

You have to edit the NAT settings in VirtualBox to forward traffic to the VM.  This does not include, unfortunately, ICMP Pings, such as those generated by the 'ping' command.  It operates on the same basis of port forwarding that Routers use.  (Except it's a much simpler thing than what routers can do.)

---

You may also want to consider using **Bridged Networking** instead, which makes the VM utilize the host's network card, but gives it its own IP on the network.  While this is 'okay' to some extent, it's not the most useful option available to you, as Bridged Networking doesn't work well with 'secured' networks.  And if you're on a wireless adapter, Bridged Networking won't give your VM 'wireless' powers.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. I have read your answer,but am still none the wiser. Would you be kind enough to enumerate the actual STEPS I need to carry out in order to be able to log into my Ubuntu machine from my VBox Ubuntu guest?.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli if you don't know how to edit the settings for your VM, then you're not going to get far.  [Read this on VM networking with VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html), and [this page explaining 'network settings' in a VM's settings](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-network).   Pay close attention to [this section on setting up the port forward](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward) if you stick to a NAT network configuration type on the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest thing to do would be to change Network interface configuration in Virtualbox and instead of Guest NAT choose Bridged networking. That way virtual machine will be in the same network as Server (as I understand Ubuntu server and Windows host are on the same network, since you can ping Ubuntu from within nated virtual machine).

The reason why you can't ping vm from server is that it has only connection through Windows host, thus it acts as NAT gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative I use with a Windows 10 host and an Ubuntu 16 guest is to use two network adapters on the guest:

- A NAT network adapter that can be used for the guest to connect to the Internet, and
- A Host-only network adapter that the guest and host can connect to each other through.